# How to configure settings.groovy in order to use several repositories?

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration-files, grails3

I just installed Grails 3.3.0 and I'd like to configure some custom repositories in the `${HOME}/user/.grails/settings.groovy` file.

[image]

This is what I've done so far (*Real URLs have been replaced for `<someUrl1|2>`*):

```
grails {
  profiles {
    repositories {
      repo1 {
        url = "<someUrl1>"
        snapshotsEnabled = true
      }
      repo2 {
        url = "<someUrl2>"
        snapshotsEnabled = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I execute `grails` command on bash (Ubutu 16.04) it always tries to resolve the dependencies from the first repository (`<someUrl1>`)

*Java:* jdk8u141

**Should this configuration be done like I did?**

If not, **How could I configure this file in order to use more than one repo for grails?**

If having connectivity issues (or whatsoever), the first attempt to connect to the first repository fails, **Does Grails tray to access the other ones declared?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should this configuration be done like I did?

Yes, according to the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/profiles.html)

> Does Grails tray to access the other ones declared?

Yes, the list of repositories are passed into the constructor of this class.
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-shell/src/main/groovy/org/grails/cli/profile/repository/MavenProfileRepository.groovy#L48